# DataConnectionDialog crashes in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, dllimport

I'm converting to **VS2017** a legacy project which uses a database connection dialog to collect data to format a connection string.

This line below is triggering an error:

```
var dialog = new DataConnectionDialog();
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93'    at
>   Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog..ctor()    at
>   Wings4CloudPackage.Forms.frmNewSolution.btnDatabase_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f4ca07f51760da93.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be
>   probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().

I have checked this path: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/` and the referenced `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll` is there.

This project uses the following nuget package to show the dialog: **DataConnectionDialog** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/1.1.0)

This code works in **VS2013**, but not in **VS2017**.

Comment: Can you run inside of Dependency Walker (use it instead of a debugger).  www.dependencywalker.com   If one of the files that `Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.dll` requires is missing, that should help identify it.

Comment: Try to start Fuslogvw - [DLL binding debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) - and check where VS tries to load the DLL from.

Answer (score 0):

For me in VS 2017 in WPF app works this:

```
        DataConnectionDialog dcd = new DataConnectionDialog();

        DataProvider dataProviderSql = DataProvider.SqlDataProvider;
        DataSource dataSourceSql = new DataSource(dataProviderSql.Name, dataProviderSql.DisplayName);
        dataSourceSql.Providers.Add(dataProviderSql);

        DataProvider dataProviderOracle = DataProvider.OracleDataProvider;
        DataSource dataSourceOracle = new DataSource(dataProviderOracle.Name, dataProviderOracle.DisplayName);
        dataSourceOracle.Providers.Add(dataProviderOracle);

        DataProvider dataProviderOle = DataProvider.OleDBDataProvider;
        DataSource dataSourceOle = new DataSource(dataProviderOle.Name, dataProviderOle.DisplayName);
        dataSourceOle.Providers.Add(dataProviderOle);

        DataProvider dataProviderOdbc = DataProvider.OdbcDataProvider;
        DataSource dataSourceOdbc = new DataSource(dataProviderOdbc.Name, dataProviderOdbc.DisplayName);
        dataSourceOdbc.Providers.Add(dataProviderOdbc);


        dcd.DataSources.Add(dataSourceSql);
        dcd.DataSources.Add(dataSourceOracle);
        dcd.DataSources.Add(dataSourceOle);
        dcd.DataSources.Add(dataSourceOdbc);

        dcd.SelectedDataSource = dataSourceSql;
        dcd.SelectedDataProvider = dataProviderSql;

        if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dcd) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("YES");
        }
```

Comment: This does not address the original question, having problems with assembly binding.

Comment: My mistake, I put the code under wrong question. This is fase two of my problem. Try look if you really reference the dll on path in your question (C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/). When I add the nuget I saw same error, I change reference from nuget dll to dll in visual studio folder and binding start work and after that I got problem which solve the code. :)